# Xcode / Build automation - How do I pass the Code Signing Identity as an argument to xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, build-automation, xcodebuild

I'm trying to automate our entire build process using hudson and a mashup of ruby scripts. Is it possible to pass the values for Versioning System, Bundle Version, Code Signing Identity and Entitlements as arguments to xcodebuild?

Answer (score 1):

+1 for using hudson to automate your build process, it makes for a great development environment.

**xcodebuild -help**

You can specify all sorts of things that should help you. You will possibly have to configure some schemes or configurations to get exactly what you need, but it should all be do-able.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using -xcconfig to override the project/target settings. I'll make sure to post it when the kinks are ironed out.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5 we are using **CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY**

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace \
    -scheme "$(SCHEME)" -derivedDataPath ./ \
    -configuration $(XCODE_BUILD_CONFIGURATION) \
    PROFILE_NAME="$(PROFILE_NAME)" \
    ARCHS="armv7" \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$(CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY)" \
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS="$(CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS)" \
    build
```